# How to print a 2d char array into a 5x5 game board and initialize it to store "O's" in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, printing

I am creating a 5x5 battleship game board. I used a nested for loop to print the board but it's not printing correctly into a 5x5 board. Can you see where I went wrong in my "for loop"?
 The instructions are to

- build a 5x5 char array(game board)
- Initialize the board to store "O's"
- Print the board

This is the output:

```
0000  0000  0000  0000  0000
0000  0000  0000  0000  0000
0000  0000  0000  0000  0000
0000  0000  0000  0000  0000
0000  0000  0000  0000  0000
```

This is the code I have so far.

```
public class Location {

    int row;
    int col;

    // constructor, gettes & setters

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       //creates array
       char[][] grid = new char [5][5];
       //prints array
       for (int row=0; row<grid.length; row++) {
           for (int col=0; col<grid[row].length; col++)
               System.out.print(grid[row][col]);
               System.out.println();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Each row of `new char[5][5]` array is filled with `nul` characters `'\0'` which can be printed differently by different tools. Consider filling your array with other characters like `*` and then print it. Compare results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Pshemo said in the comments, you need to initialize your grid.

```
// creates array
char[][] grid = new char [5][5];

// initialize array
for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; ++row) {
    for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; ++col)
        grid[row][col] = 'O';
}
```